# How to convert seconds to minutes and seconds?

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

New to coding! I want to make a simple countdown timer that counts down from 53 minutes. How can I format the output like "52:58" instead of "3178" (seconds)? Thanks! :)

This is what I have:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var counter = 0;
  var timeleft = 3180;

  function convertSeconds(s) {
    var min = floor (s / 60);
    var sec = s % 60;
    return min + ':' + sec;

  }

  function setup() {
    var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
    timer.innerHTML = (convertSeconds(timeleft - counter));

    function timeIt() {
      counter++;
      timer.innerHTML = (convertSeconds(timeleft - counter));
    }
    setInterval(timeIt, 1000);
  }
  setup();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 3):

use `Math.floor` instead of `floor`. Your code already doing all what you want :)

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var counter = 0;
  var timeleft = 3180;

  function convertSeconds(s) {
    var min = Math.floor (s / 60);
    var sec = s % 60;
    return min + ':' + sec;

  }

  function setup() {
    var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
    timer.innerHTML = (convertSeconds(timeleft - counter));

    function timeIt() {
      counter++;
      timer.innerHTML = (convertSeconds(timeleft - counter));
    }
    setInterval(timeIt, 1000);
  }
  setup();
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Math.floor()`function to calculate values in minutes and
seconds.

Comment: Hmmm, not really. Math.floor() is used to round numbers, not to calculate a value in minutes and seconds :)

Comment: It will actually if you put parameters in it like math.floor(value*60)  for converting in minutes to seconds.